# Express response doesn't work when using mongoose and async

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm using express and mongoose. I have a weird issue when I'm using mocha test to run this endpoint.

```
exports.broadcastMessages = function(req, res, next) {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if(err) return next(err);

    var push = function(user, callback) {
      user.messages.push(req.body.message);
      user.save(function(err) {
        callback(err);
      });
    };

    var fin = function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      console.log('aaaaaaaaaa');
      return res.send('ok');
    };

    async.each(users, push, fin);
  });
};
```

Then I got a timeout error. There is only one user. So it's not a time issue. And I'm sure res.send('ok') was called. But when I removed user.save(). It worked...

```
exports.broadcastMessages = function(req, res, next) {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if(err) return next(err);

    var push = function(user, callback) {
      user.messages.push(req.body.message);
      callback(err);
    };

    var fin = function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      console.log('aaaaaaaaaa');
      return res.send('ok');
    };

    async.each(users, push, fin);
  });
};
```

I don't know why. Why added one more user.save() it doesn't work? res.send is called but no response.

The version of express is 3.4.7. Mongoose is 3.8.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "I got a timeout error" do you mean mocha failed your test for taking too long? If so that is probably a problem in your mocha test itself not calling `done()` correctly. The above code looks OK to me and I think it should work. Some misc points:

Whenever you have this pattern:

```
user.save(function(err) {
  callback(err);
});
```

You don't need that extra wrapper function that does nothing but call the callback. Just do:

```
user.save(callback);
```

Also, looping through the users and saving each one is much less efficient than just having mongodb do them all for you in a single command:

```
User.update({}, {$push: {messages: req.body.message}}, function (error) {...});
```

Comment: Oh yes haha I forgot calling `done()` in mocha test. Thanks a lot!